# Переклад терміна "e-mail" українською мовою

Tags: переклад, from-english

При виконанні мною перекладу українською мовою часто виникали сумніви щодо терміна "e-mail". В текстах-оригіналах написаних українською мовою зустрічалося вживання як "е-мейл", так і залишалося англомовне написання "e-mail". То яке все ж таки доречне використання?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Щодо перекладу терміна, то однозначного перекладу не знайшла. Здебільшого трапляються наступні варіанти.

в [англійсько-українському словнику з ІТ](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=email&main_only=&highlight=on) подають так:

> email = електронна пошта

В [Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики 2010р. (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко)](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=email&main_only=&highlight=on) міститься такий переклад:

> address <…>
>
> - e(-)mail ~ = електро́нна адре́са.

Автори [Англійсько-українсько-англійського словника наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки). Частина І англійсько-українська 2010р. (О. Кочерга, Є. Мейнарович)](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=email&main_only=&highlight=on) вважаю, що:

> box <…>
>
> - email ~ = бокс [скри́нька] електро́нної по́шти.

На цьому ж сайті [Dict.com](https://www.dict.com/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B8/e-mail) перекладають термін так:

> e-mail n
>
> Однина    e-mail
>
> Множина   e-mails
>
> (інформ.) еме́йл, електро́нна по́шта

З Вашого дозволу висловлю і свою думку. Я вважаю, що краще використовувати для письма українською мовою, але не сам термін, а його відповідник. Адже це те саме, що писати якийсь твір і вживати, наприклад, замість слова мама англійське *"mum"*.

Comment: Ще можна спробувати варіант "е-пошта".

Comment: Зауважу, що знак тильди («~») у словнику зазвичай заміняє слово, якого стосується словникова стаття. Тобто «електро́нна адре́са» — це переклад для «e(-)mail **box**» (оскільки «e(-)mail ~» було написано всередині словникової статті про «box»), а «бокс [скри́нька] електро́нної по́шти» — це переклад для «email **address**» (оскільки «email ~» було написано всередині словникової статті про «address»). Я додам пропущені слова, щоб вони не випадали з контексту, якщо Ви не проти.

Answer (score 2):

Олександр Пономарів
Доктор філологічних наук, академік АН Вищої школи України.
Професор Київського національного університету імені Тараса Шевченка.
Член Національної комісії України з питань правопису.
[Веде мовний блог на BBC Україна з 2009 року.](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-44698972)

> Якщо відтворювати не написання, а вимову англійського e-mail, то потрібно писати і-мейл